# Laravel 5.2 query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I try to get this query to work:

```
DB::select(
    DB::raw('select 
        sum(case when outreach_links.status="Pending" and outreach_links.created_at >= :from and outreach_links.created_at <=:to then 1 else 0 end) as pp,
        sum(case when outreach_links.status="Approved" and outreach_links.start_date >= :from and outreach_links.start_date <=:to then 1 else 0 end) as aa,
        sum(case when outreach_links.status="Approved" then outreach_links.cost else 0 end) as cc,
        MONTH(outreach_links.created_at) month,
        MONTHNAME(outreach_links.created_at) month_name,
        YEAR(outreach_links.created_at) year from outreach
        inner join outreach_links on outreach.id = outreach_links.outreach_id
        where outreach.profile_id=:proid
        group by month, year',
    ["from" => $from, "to" => $to, "proid" => $pro_id])
)->get();
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

---

I changed to this and it worked:

```
DB::select(
    DB::raw('select 
        sum(case when outreach_links.status="Pending" and outreach_links.created_at >= ? and outreach_links.created_at <=? then 1 else 0 end) as pp,
        sum(case when outreach_links.status="Approved" and outreach_links.start_date >= ? and outreach_links.start_date <=? then 1 else 0 end) as aa,
        sum(case when outreach_links.status="Approved" then outreach_links.cost else 0 end) as cc,
        MONTH(outreach_links.created_at) month,
        MONTHNAME(outreach_links.created_at) month_name,
        YEAR(outreach_links.created_at) year from outreach
        inner join outreach_links on outreach.id = outreach_links.outreach_id
        where outreach.profile_id=?
        group by month, year'),
    [$from, $to, $from, $to, $pro_id]
);
```

Comment: `I changed it to this and it worked` what's the problem then?

Comment: The second part should be an answer, not an insert into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DB::raw() doesn't parse the query.](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) Try moving your conditions outside the `raw` call:

```
DB::select(
    DB::raw('select 
        sum(case when outreach_links.status="Pending" and outreach_links.created_at >= :from and outreach_links.created_at <=:to then 1 else 0 end) as pp,
        sum(case when outreach_links.status="Approved" and outreach_links.start_date >= :from and outreach_links.start_date <=:to then 1 else 0 end) as aa,
        sum(case when outreach_links.status="Approved" then outreach_links.cost else 0 end) as cc,
        MONTH(outreach_links.created_at) month,
        MONTHNAME(outreach_links.created_at) month_name,
        YEAR(outreach_links.created_at) year from outreach
        inner join outreach_links on outreach.id = outreach_links.outreach_id
        where outreach.profile_id=:proid
        group by month, year'),
    ["from" => $from, "to" => $to, "proid" => $pro_id]
)->get();
```

Comment: I am getting an error:  Invalid parameter number> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select
sum(case when outreach_links.status="Pending" and outreach_links.created_at >= :from and outreach_links.created_at <=:to then 1 else 0 end) as pp,
sum(case when outreach_links.status="Approved" and outreach_links.start_date >= :from and outreach_links.start_date <=:to then 1 else 0 end) as aa,

Comment: Can you try removing the internal raw call and keeping the select?

Comment: I removed the get and tried with "?" and it worked - check my question edits , is that the best way to do it?